# Scrollbar appear but not scrolling

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make responsive popup signup and signin form.when site open in  extra small size device some text of form doesn't show.i want to scroll overlay but not scrolling. please kindly help.Code is given below

Html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Cover of Quiz Up</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="site-wrapper"  >

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner" >

        <div class="cover-container" >

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1 class="masthead-brand">Quiz Up</h1>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Take Quiz</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">What's New</h1>
            <p class="lead">A system created to help students enhance their skills regarding their courses or subjects of interest.Covering a wide range of concepts and giving more exposure to students</p>
            <p class="lead">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Sign Up</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">  <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Sign In</a></div>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
        <header class="popupHeader">
            <span class="header_title">Login</span>
            <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </header>

        <section class="popupBody">
            <!-- Social Login -->
            <div class="social_login">
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#" class="social_box fb">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
                        <span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>

                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="social_box google">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="icon_title">Connect with Google</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="centeredText">
                    <span>Or use your Email address</span>
                </div>

                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" id="login_form" class="btn">Login</a></div>
                    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn">Sign up</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Username & Password Login form -->

            <div class="user_login">

                <form  >
                    <label>Email / Username</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>


                <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>

            </div>

            <!-- Register Form -->
            <div class="user_register">
                <form>
                    <label>Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="send_updates" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="send_updates">Send me occasional email updates</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
            </div>


          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p >Copyright © 2014 All Rights Reserved Design by Waqas Iqbal</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 100, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close"
        });

    $(function(){
        // Calling Login Form
        $("#login_form").click(function(){
            $(".social_login").hide();
            $(".user_login").show();
            return false;
        });

        // Calling Register Form
        $("#register_form").click(function(){
            $(".social_login").hide();
            $(".user_register").show();
            $(".header_title").text('Register');
            return false;
        });

        // Going back to Social Forms
        $(".back_btn").click(function(){
            $(".user_login").hide();
            $(".user_register").hide();
            $(".social_login").show();
            $(".header_title").text('Login');
            return false;
        });

    })
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,700italic,400italic);

body {font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;}

#lean_overlay {

    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.popupContainer{
    position:fixed;
    width:330px;
    height: auto;
    left:45%;
    top:80px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#modal_trigger {margin:auto; width:100px; display:block;}

.btn {padding:10px 20px; background: #F4F4F2;}
.btn_red {background: #ED6347; color: #FFF;}

.btn:hover {background: #E4E4E2;}
.btn_red:hover {background: #C12B05;}

a.btn {color:#666; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;}
a.btn_red {color: #FFF;}

.one_half {width:50%; display: block; float:left;}
.one_half.last {width:45%; margin-left:5%;}

/* Popup Styles*/
.popupHeader {font-size:16px; text-transform: uppercase;}
.popupHeader {background:#F4F4F2; position:relative; padding:10px 20px; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD; font-weight:bold;}
.popupHeader .modal_close {position: absolute; right: 0; top:0; padding:10px 15px; background:#E4E4E2; cursor: pointer; color:#aaa; font-size:16px;}

.popupBody {padding:20px;pos}


/* Social Login Form */
.social_login {}
.social_login .social_box {display:block; clear:both; padding:10px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: #F4F4F2; overflow: hidden;}
.social_login .icon {display:block; width:40px; padding:5px 10px; margin-right: 10px; float:left; color:#FFF; font-size:16px; text-align: center;} 
.social_login .fb .icon {background:#3B5998;}
.social_login .google .icon {background:#DD4B39;}
.social_login .icon_title {display:block; padding:5px 0; float:left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color:#777;}
.social_login .social_box:hover {background: #E4E4E2;}

.centeredText {text-align: center; margin: 20px 0; clear: both; overflow: hidden; text-transform: uppercase;}

.action_btns {clear:both; overflow: hidden;}
.action_btns a {display: block;}

/* User Login Form */
.user_login {display: none;}
.user_login label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px;}
.user_login input[type="text"], .user_login input[type="email"], .user_login input[type="password"] {display: block; width:90%; padding: 10px; border:1px solid #DDD; color:#666;}
.user_login input[type="checkbox"] {float:left; width:20%;}
.user_login input[type="checkbox"]+label {float:left;}
.user_login .checkbox {margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both; margin-right:5px;}
.forgot_password {display:block; margin: 20px 0 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden; text-decoration: none; color:#ED6347;}
/* User Register Form */
.user_register {display: none;}
.user_register label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px;}
.user_register input[type="text"], .user_register input[type="email"], .user_register input[type="password"] {display: block; width:90%; padding: 10px; border:1px solid #DDD; color:#666;}
.user_register input[type="checkbox"] {float:left; margin-right:5px;}
.user_register input[type="checkbox"]+label {float:left;}

.user_register .checkbox {margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden;}
```

jquery

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.extend({
    leanModal: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            top: 100,
            overlay: 0.5,
            closeButton: null
        };
        var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
        $("body").append(overlay);
        $("body").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
        $("#lean_overlay").css({"overflow-y":"scroll"});
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var o = options;
            var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");

            function showModal() {
                $("#lean_overlay").click(function () {

                });
                $(o.closeButton).click(function () {
                    close_modal(modal_id)
                });

                var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();



                $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);

                $(modal_id).css({

                    "position": "fixed",
                    "opacity": 0,
                    "z-index": 1000,
                    "left": 50 + "%",
                    "margin-left": -(modal_width / 2) + "px",
                    "top": o.top + "px"
                });

                $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
            };

            $(document).ready(function () {
                showModal();
            });

            $(this).click(function (e) {
                showModal();
                e.preventDefault()
            })
        });

        function close_modal(modal_id) {
            $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
            $(modal_id).css({
                "display": "none"
            })
        }
    }
})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You need media queries to edit your css

Comment: which kind of media queries?

Comment: No one have any solution of this problem???